# Make my intro page appear only one time by user or computer

Tags: php, javascript

i have a question, i have a index.php page that is the intro of my website, when the intro starts and finishes it redirects to my home.php page, but i want to make this intro page appear only one time by user or by computer, if the user already been to the intro page he will be redirectally sent to the home page whitout going to the index.php (intro) page.
How can i achieve it in php?

Comment: Have you tried looking into cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
index.php

if(isset($_COOKIE['visit'])){
header("Location:home.php");
}

Your Intro

setCookie("visit","1",time()+60*60*7*12);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could send the user a cookie so that you can recognize that cookie, when he comes back. Though setting cookies isn't nice and the user might delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try and set a cookie when the first time the user lands on the home page. That way the next time the user comes to your site you can look for the cookie before the intro plays.

[How to set a cookie in php](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp)

Answer (score 0):

There is no 100% way to do this. You can use `$_SESSION` or `$_COOKIE` to save some data for current user (e.g. that he or she has visited this site), but he will see intro again if he opens up your site in different browser. User can also clear cookies, so he or she will see intro again.

If your site implements membership, where users can stay logged in, then you can store this information in database (or other data source), so user will not see intro (unless (s)he logouts).

Example of using session to store some info for current user (it doesn't require membership or the likes, it will work, because data is saved for every user visiting your site):

```
<?php
    // index.php
    // if you prefer to use cookies instead of sessions
    // then replace $_SESSION with $_COOKIE
    $hasVisited = ($_SESSION['hasVisited'] === true);
    if($hasVisited) {
        header("Location: home.php");
        die();
    }

    // here you show your intro

    // user has visited this site, so:
    $_SESSION['hasVisited'] = true;
?>
```

Explanation for differences between cookies and session: [Cookies vs. Sessions](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/10/1/0).

Comment: No, there isnt a membership, nothing of this, there is no problem if the person opens other browser, but if i want to do it how would a do it?, very nice the example you gave me, but this is good if it would have any kind of memebershio or somethign, but in my case, that the isnt, i would i do it?

Comment: @mauro Check my edited post, this example will work for every user visiting your site, it doesn't require membership.

Comment: @jenny session expire, cookie expire, the difference here is client vs server side (and expiration timeout). I prefer not to store data in cookies because it can be easily edited by user.